# How to create a literal XML string with swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, swift2

I wants to generate XML string something like this in swift -

```
<userTracking>
    <userDetail id='1178085'>xxxx</userDetail>
    <trackInfo type="xxxxx" type_id="xxxxxxx" attending="x" event_date="2016-07-01"/>
</userTracking>
```

for this i had objective-C code -

```
NSString *post = @"";
post = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"<userTracking>"
                @"<userDetail id=\'%@\'>xxxxx</userDetail>"
                @"<trackInfo type=\"%@\" type_id=\"%@\" attending=\"%@\" event_date=\"%@\"/>"
                @"</userTracking>"
                , UserID,type, typeID, attending,event_date];
```

which is working great. Now i wants to generate same thing in swift & done following code but getting wrong XML formatted string -

swift Code -

```
 var post  = "";
 post = "<userTracking>" +
            "<userDetail id='\(UserID)\'>xxxxx</userDetail>" +
            "<trackInfo type=\"\(type)\" type_id=\"\(typeID)\" attending=\"\(attending)\" event_date=\"\(event_date)\"/>" +
        "</userTracking>";
```

Result in Swift -

```
 <userTracking>
     <userDetail id=\'xxxxx\'>xxxxx</userDetail>
     <trackInfo type=\"xxxx\" type_id=\"xxx\" attending=\"4\" event_date=\"2016-07-01\"/>
    </userTracking>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `failed` How? What is the error?

Comment: @EricD in swift getting Wrong XML string . which is - <userTracking><userDetail id=\'xxxxx\'>xxxxx</userDetail><trackInfo type=\"xxxx\" type_id=\"xxx\" attending=\"4\" event_date=\"2016-07-01\"/></userTracking>

Comment: look up how to add newline and tab characters if it's the formatting you're worried about, but so long as all tags are opened/closed in order an xml file can be a single string of all elements - it's just harder to read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `String(format:)` in Swift.

Don't forget to escape all double quotes, and add newlines ("\n") and tabs ("\t") if needed.

Example:

```
let post = String(format: "<userTracking>\n\t<userDetail id=\'%@\'>xxxxx</userDetail>\n\t<trackInfo type=\"%@\" type_id=\"%@\" attending=\"%@\" event_date=\"%@\"/>\n</userTracking>", UserID, type, typeID, attending, event_date)
```

Gives:

```
<userTracking>  
    <userDetail id='...'>xxxxx</userDetail>  
    <trackInfo type="..." type_id="..." attending="..." event_date="..."/>  
</userTracking>
```

Comment: Thanks @EricD  Great - :)